# UIBarButtonItem Moves From Side to Center

Tags: ios

I have a UIToolbar with UIBarButtonItem on left and right.

**First time go to screen**:
[image]

**Subsequent**:
[image]

Anyone knows why UIBarButtonItem goes from side to center? For sure, there is no code inside my application to move UIBarButtonItem.

**Note**

Using code or load it from XIB both have same result.

Comment: What do you mean by subsequently going to the screen? Relaunching the app or just navigating to some other screen and returning to it?

Comment: Seems to be rendering problem. Unless the code is there doing it manually somehow. Two way issue like this can occur either you are programmatically doing it or you are doing nothing that is why it doen't render properly each time.

Comment: show your xib to get better idea

Comment: Looks like Auto Layout constraints are not configured correctly.

Comment: I am not using Auto Layout. My XIB is just a normal XIB file with Toolbar and UIBarButtonItem on each side, then connect them to my view controller.

Comment: You want to set "Cancel" on left most and "Done" on right most ?